# Raspberry PI4 usb 3.0 seems not working properly

Tags: usb-power, raspberry-pi-os, power-management, usb-hub, usb3

I am using a Raspberry PI4 with **Google Coral TPU** and a **Telit Lte modem** both attached  on **USB 3.0 ports**. 
I get a lot of **"Under-Voltage"** messages also using the Raspberry power supply(5.1V, 3A).
Trying to analyze the problem it would seem that the devices connected to the USB 3.0 ports are recognized on the 2.0 hub as described in the follow:

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb` 
`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub` 
`Bus 001 Device 008: ID 18d1:9302 Google Inc.`  
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1bc7:1201 Telit Wireless Solutions`  
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub` 
`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

`Bus 001 Device 008` is the **Google Coral TPU** and `BUS 001 Device 009` is the **Telit Lte modem**

Running `lsusb -t` I have this result:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qmi_wwan, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 4, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 5, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 6, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
```

Both devices are recognized on the 2.0 usb at 480M and no devices seems to be attached to the USB 3.0 ports.

Trying an `lsusb -v` I found that:
**Google Coral TPU** consumes **498mA** 
**Telit Lte module** consumes **500mA**.
**100mA** are consumed by **VIA Labs, Inc. Hub**.
So I should stay within the **1200 mhA** declared by Raspberry on the USB ports

My questions are:

1. Why my devices are not recognized in the usb 3.0 hub?
2. Moreover, why I get under voltage messages? Is it a kind of "power safe" that downgrade usb 3.0 into 2.0?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please clarify your hardware setup. Is the USB3 hub external or built-in? Is this Telit module a USB2 or USB3 device? etc. Also, if you're getting undervoltage messages your PSU or cable is not OK, you need to deal with that first.

Comment: I use the Raspberry Pi4 USB3 built-in Hub(2 ports) to connect both Coral TPU and SixFab Base HAT equipped with Telit LE910C1-EU Lte Modem. Coral TPU is reccomended to use in USB3 as the provided 3.0 USB cable. The SixFab Base HAT USB version is not specified